# Routing/Modularity in Dojo (Single Page Application)

Tags: dojo

I worked with backbone before and was wondering if there's a similar way to achieve this kind of pattern in dojo. Where you have a router and pass one by one your view separately (like layers) and then you can add their intern functionality somewhere else (e.g inside the view) so the code is very modular and can be change/add new stuff very easily. This code is actually in jquery (and come from a previous project) and it's a "common" base pattern to develop single application page under jquery/backbone.js .

**main.js**

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({

routes: {
        "home"                  : "home"},
home: function(){

        if (!this.homeView) {
            this.homeView= new HomeView();
        }
        $('#content').html(this.homeView.el);

        this.homeView.selectMenuItem('home-link');
    }};

utils.loadTemplate(['HomeView'], function() {
    app = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

**utils.js**

```
loadTemplate: function(views, callback) {

        var deferreds = [];

        $.each(views, function(index, view) {
            if (window[view]) {
                deferreds.push($.get('tpl/' + view + '.html', function(data) {
                    window[view].prototype.template = _.template(data);
                }));
            } else {
                alert(view + " not found");
            }
        });

        $.when.apply(null, deferreds).done(callback);
    }};
```

**HomeView.js**

```
window.HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize:function () {
        this.render();
    },

    render:function () {
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        return this;
    }

});
```

And basically, you just pass the html template. This pattern can be called anywhere with this link:

```
<li class="active"><a href="#home"><i class="icon-home"></i> Dashboard</a></li>
```

Or, what is the best way to implement this using dojo boilerplate.

Comment: seing a jquery '$' reference... this.el is as ExtJS would set it up - and you're going at it in dojo - no wonder youre getting confused :p

Comment: in the edited code in my answer below, the Utils.js can be left out, dojo loader handles that. Also, HomeView is basically implemented via ContentPane, but the Abstract gives possibility to extend. In my 'Main' (aka Application) there's a dijit.tree with 'links', each referenced with a view component (which has `href` set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'boilerplate' on this subject is a dojox.mvc app. Reference is here.

From another aspect, see my go at it a while back, ive setup an abstract for 'controller' which then builds a view in its implementation.

[Abstract](https://github.com/mschr/oocms/blob/master/admin/include/AbstractController.js)

Then i have an [application](https://github.com/mschr/oocms/blob/master/admin/include/application.js) controller, which does following on its menu.onClick

1. which fires loading icon,
2. unloads current pane (if forms are not dirty)
3. loads modules it needs (defined 'routes' in a main-menu-store)
4. setup view pane with a new, requested one

Each view is either simply a server-html page or built with a declared 'oocms' controller module. Simplest example of [abstract implementation here](https://github.com/mschr/oocms/blob/master/admin/include/config.js) . Each implements an unload feature and a startup feature where we would want to dereference stores or eventhooks in teardown - and in turn, assert stores gets loaded etc in the setup.

If you wish to use templates, then base your views on the dijit._TemplatedMixin

### *edit*

Here is a simplified clarification of my oocms setup, where instead of basing it on BorderLayout, i will make it ContentPanes:

#### Example JSON for the menu, with a single item representing the above declared view

```
 {
    identifier: 'view',
    label: 'name',
    items: [
      { name: 'myForm', view: 'App.view.MyForm', extraParams: { foo: 'bar' } }
    ]
 }
```

#### Base Application Controller in file 'AppPackagePath/Application.js'

Note, the code has not been tested but should give a good impression of how such a setup can be implemented

```
 define(['dojo/_base/declare', 
"dojo/_base/lang",
"dijit/registry",
"OoCmS/messagebus", // dependency mixin which will monitor 'notify/progress' topics'
"dojo/topic",
"dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore",
"dijit/tree/ForestStoreModel",
"dijit/Tree"

], function(declare, lang, registry, msgbus, dtopic, itemfilereadstore, djforestmodel, djtree) {
    return declare("App.Application", [msgbus], {

        paneContainer: NULL,
        treeContainer: NULL,
        menuStoreUrl: '/path/to/url-list',
        _widgetInUse: undefined,
        defaultPaneProps: {},
        loading: false, // ismple mutex
        constructor: function(args) {
            lang.mixin(this, args);
            if(!this.treeContainer || !this.paneContainer) {
                console.error("Dont know where to place components")
            }
            this.defaultPaneProps = {
                id: 'mainContentPane'
            }
            this.buildRendering();
        },
        buildRendering: function() {
            this.menustore = new itemfilereadstore({
                id: 'appMenuStore',
                url:this.menuStoreUrl
            });
            this.menumodel = new djforestmodel({
                id: 'appMenuModel',
                store: this.menustore
            });
            this.menu = new djtree( {
                model: this.menumodel,
                showRoot: false,
                autoExpand: true,
                onClick: lang.hitch(this, this.paneRequested) // passes the item
            })
                            // NEEDS a construct ID HERE
            this.menu.placeAt(this.treeContainer)
        },
        paneRequested: function(item) {
            if(this.loading || !item) {
                console.warn("No pane to load, give me a menustore item");
                return false;
            }
            if(!this._widgetInUse || !this._widgetInUse.isDirty()) {
                dtopic.publish("notify/progress/loading");
                this.loading = true;
            }
            if(typeof this._widgetInUse != "undefined") {
                if(!this._widgetInUse.unload()) {
                    // bail out if widget says 'no' (isDirty)
                    return false;
                }
                this._widgetInUse.destroyRecursive();
                delete this._widgetInUse;
            }

            var self = this,
                modules = [this.menustore.getValue(item, 'view')];
            require(modules, function(viewPane) {
                self._widgetInUse = new viewPane(self.defaultProps);

                            // NEEDS a construct ID HERE

                self._widgetInUse.placeAt(this.paneContainer)
                self._widgetInUse.ready.then(function() {
                    self.paneLoaded();
                })
            });
            return true;
        },
        paneLoaded: function() {
            // hide ajax icons
            dtopic.publish("notify/progress/done");
            // assert widget has started
            this._widgetInUse.startup();
            this.loading = false;
        }
    })
})
```

#### AbstractView in file 'AppPackagePath/view/AbstractView.js':

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
"dojo/_base/Deferred",
"dojo/_base/lang",
"dijit/registry",
"dijit/layout/ContentPane"], function(declare, deferred, lang, registry, contentpane) {

    return declare("App.view.AbstractView", [contentpane], {
        observers: [],      // all programmatic events handles should be stored for d/c on unload
        parseOnLoad: false,
        constructor: function(args) {
            lang.mixin(this, args)
            // setup ready.then resolve
            this.ready = new deferred();
            // once ready, create
            this.ready.then(lang.hitch(this, this.postCreate));
            // the above is actually not nescessary, since we could simply use onLoad in contentpane
            if(typeof this.content != "undefined") {
                this.set("content", this.content);
                this.onLoad();
            } else if(typeof 'href' == "undefined") {
                console.warn("No contents nor href set in construct");
            }
        },
        startup : function startup() {
            this.inherited(arguments);
        },
        // if you override this, make sure to this.inherited(arguments);
        onLoad: function() {
            dojo.parser.parse(this.contentNode);
            // alert the application, that loading is done
            this.ready.resolve(null);
            // and call render
            this.render();
        },
        render: function() {
            console.info('no custom rendering performed in ' + this.declaredClass)
        },
        isDirty: function() { return false; },
        unload: function() {
            dojo.forEach(this.observers, dojo.disconnect);
            return true;
        },
        addObserver: function() {
            // simple passthrough, adding the connect to handles
            var handle = dojo.connect.call(dojo.window.get(dojo.doc), 
                arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2]);
            this.observers.push(handle);
        }
    });

});
```

#### View implementation sample in file 'AppPackagePath/view/MyForm.js':

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare",
"dojo/_base/lang",
"App/view/AbstractView",
// the contentpane href will pull in some html
// in the html can be markup, which will be renderered when ready
// pull in requirements here
"dijit/form/Form",  // markup require
"dijit/form/Button" // markup require
], function(declare, lang, baseinterface) {
    return declare("App.view.MyForm", [baseinterface], {
        // using an external HTML file
        href: 'dojoform.html',
        _isDirty : false,
        isDirty: function() {
            return this._isDirty;
        },
        render: function() {
            var self = this;
            this.formWidget = dijit.byId('embeddedForm') // hook up with loaded markup
            // observer for children
            dojo.forEach(this.formWidget._getDescendantFormWidgets(), function(widget){
                if(! lang.isFunction(widget.onChange) )
                    console.log('unable to observe ' + widget.id);
                self.addObserver(widget, 'onChange', function() {
                    self._isDirty = true;
                });
            });
        // 
        },

        // @override
        unload: function() {
            if(this.isDirty()) {
                var go = confirm("Sure you wish to leave page before save?")
                if(!go) return false;
            }
            return this.inherited(arguments);

        }
    })
});
```

Comment: hmm I was actually looking into dojox/app or dojox/mvc ? I'll try to look at your code, but it seems pretty advanced to me (in Dojo, I'm "new" been doing example/documentation since 1/2 weeks). I just want a good pattern to start my application... I am confuse on how to actually begin something nice in Dojo (Modular - MVC alike).  There's not much more example on that matter too.

Comment: Try make use of layout.ContentPane (dojox version evaluates scripts also). Ive ammended my answer with a basic setup - in general; `dijit.layout.ContentPane.set("href", url);` and `dijit.layout.ContentPane.onLoad = function() { }` gets you a long way

Comment: hmmm. What exacly is /path/to/url-list? It's my json right... Secondly, in application.js, my paneContainer and treeContainer is null, so I guess I need to pass my own from my index.html?

Comment: There actually getting 1.8 out this week I think (with documentation) and there's something called dojox/app and dojox/route to implement a MVC infrastruture (aka Modular components).

Comment: Yea.. but its a loong long story bro! The dojox.mvc is allready present in current version - the 1.8 will simply refine (and bloat it a bit more :) Find a detailed story here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ejZlUwySI0q3n3scInw30drHa7no7Zm-WSZqtYx5scE/

Comment: ahm temporary link it seems - go : http://dojotoolkit.org/blog/whats-coming-in-dojo-1-8 and click 'release roadmap', then find the link under dojox.mvc (Application framework)